# How can I call a method after a Blazor Select is populated with its data?

Tags: blazor

In Blazor, I am populating a Select control with a simple List. I have the @onchange event working, but trying to figure out how to trigger a method call upon the list being loaded into the Select.

```
<select @onloadeddata=@SelectLoaded
        @onchange=@SelectChanged
        id="clientSelect"
        class="col-md-2">
  @foreach (var client in ClientList)
  {
    <option value="@client">@client</option>
  }
</select>
```

Is there an event on the Select that I can use? I've tried all of the ones that seem logical, but they don't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call SelectLoaded when your select data (Presumably Client list?) is fetched, generally in the OnInitializedAsync - but it depends on your component.

In blazor server, the server does all the data loading etc and only sends the diffed HTML nodes to the browser script. The browser script is devoid of any component logic. Unlike JS based application, there is no client side data loading as such in a practical sense.

Comment: Ok, so if I get what you're suggesting (and it works as I've written it), I just need to add a call in my constructor to a method that:
a) sets the selected item,
b) calls the method that I want to run on any selection changes,
Correct?

Comment: Two methods: 1. SelectLoaded - what you want to do when the data is loaded first time (set a default selection etc) This should be in the Initialized 2. SelectChanged - what you do every time selection changes - this remains as you have written.